# ASP.NET MVC 2 - ViewData empty after POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, controller, viewdata

I don't really know where to look for an error... the situation: I have an ASPX view which contains a form and a few input's, and when I click the submit button everything is POST'ed to one of my ASP.NET MVC actions.

When I set a breakpoint there, it is hit correctly. When I use FireBug to see what is sent to the action, I correctly see data1=abc&data2=something&data3=1234.

However, nothing is arriving in my action method. ViewData is empty, there is no ViewData["data1"] or anything else that would show that data arrived.

How can this be? Where can I start looking for the error?

Comment: wrt data1=abc&data2=... what does the method signature for your action method look like?

Comment: No parameters. ViewData["data1"] should be able to access the value. But it's null, even though FireBug shows that the value was submitted.

Comment: What do you expect to find in ViewData in a postback? It is used for the controller to send data to the view and not vice-versa. Look in `Request["data1"]` or even better in the parameters of the controller action.

Comment: Clearly I didn't have enough sleep last night. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex, @Darin is 100% correct, esp with the adive that you should use parameters. shy away from magic strings etc

Comment: you know guys, actually there is no postback in mvc :), it's just post

Comment: @David: I was actually using parameters in my original function but couldn't get model binding to work, then created a test method without parameters, and the rest is history. Of course the FormCollection shouldn't be accessed directly.

Comment: @Omu, yeah no postback in mvc and thanks God :-) Good remark.

Comment: Guys, if ViewData is not posted from a view to a controller, then what is really meant in the [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewdata%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) section of the docs? This: "The view can add to or change the data, which will be sent to the controller when the view is posted as part of a request." I have not used it and I have no idea how it could work. I just would like to understand what is meant in the docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ViewData is relevant when going from the controller to the view.  It won't post back.

you'll need your action method to look something like

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(string data1, string data2, int data3) { ...
```

Then the (model? parameter?) binding should take care of things for you

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your Action to accept FormCollection:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(FormCollection fc)
{
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline(fc["data1"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what is posted to your View, accept FormCollection as a parameter, or bind your form elements directly to a model.  Like so:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult PostToThisView(FormCollection formItems)
{
    var data1 = formItems["data1"];
    return View();
}
```

Also, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504681/formcollection-empty-on-form-post-in-asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Request["data1"]
```

or

```
Request.Form["data1"]
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourPostAction(object data1)
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourPostAction(ACLassThatHasData1Prop viewmodel)
//your view doesn't has to be strongly typed to the type of the parameter in this case
```

Comment: Regarding the last example, the model used for the parameter doesn't have to be the same as the model that is strongly-typed to the view from which the request came.  The model binder will simply take the values stored in the forms collection (or the query string if the request is a GET) and try to used them to populate whatever type of object is specified as the parameter.

Comment: @Dr. Wily's Apprentice, thnx for telling me that